# Publish and subscribe the POST restful client in the WSO2 API-1.7

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a post restful client which I need to publish.I am able to publish the same and post subscription, what would be the payload parameters as its a restful client.As I go through the WSO2 docs, they all refer to SOAP requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to send SOAP requests to WSO2 api manager. You can configure api manager to build the message to send to the backend service using you incoming request body (either json or SOAP request)

for example try this [sample](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/Convert+a+JSON+Message+to+SOAP+and+SOAP+to+JSON). This shows how a JSON request is converted to a SOAP payload to access SOAP web service backend. Here payload factory mediator is used to convert the JSON message to SOAP message. if you do not use that mediators, you would be able to send the incomming JSON body directly to backend service (if backend accepts JSON)

Comment: this worked for me.As mentioned I only created the payload factory to pass the query params and need not create the JSONtoSOAP or SOAPtoJSON sequences.